# Instantiating a controller that uses an isolate scope for a test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

So I have a controller test file with:

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
ctrlInstance = $controller( 'formCtrl', { $scope: scope } );
```

This controller isn't getting instantiated correctly, because the scope that I'm passing in doesn't have data that it normally has (due to being passed from an isolate scope).

These are the first few lines of my formCtrl:

```
var vm = this;
vm.stats = angular.copy( vm.statsStuff ); 
vm.stats.showX = vm.stats.showY = true;
```

Note that vm.statsStuff has data bound to it (due to a '=' scope in the corresponding directive), but I'm not sure how to pass it these values when I instantiate my controller in the test.

Any help would be appreciated.

Adding directive:

```
angular.module( 'myModule' )
    .directive( 'formStuff', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'dir.tpl.html',
            scope: {
                statsStuff: '='
            },
            controller: 'formStuffCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'formCtrl',
            bindToController: true
        };
    } );
})();
```

Comment: You should show your directive and your controller. I think I understand what you mean, but it would be a lot clearer if we saw the relevant parts of your code. I guess you're using controllerAs and bindToController, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. When my unit test creates my directive it can't instantiate the controller because vm.statsStuff is undefined. So it makes vm.stats undefined which causes the 3rd line in the controller to break.

Comment: You could simply... not use controllerAs nor bindToController, and everything would be so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular-mocks module has a [$controller](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/api/ngMock/service/$controller) service that decorates the "real" one, and allows passing a third argument, containing data to bind to the controller before instantiating it.

So all you should need is

```
ctrlInstance = $controller('formCtrl', { $scope: scope }, { statsStuff: theStuff } );
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, but this seems to be in Angular 1.4. I'm using 1.3 so it didn't work for me. But it's definitely good to know when I upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Until you upgrade to `1.4` (when doing so, JB's answer is **the way**), I would do the following to "emulate" what the third parameter is doing (to some extent*):

```
var $scope, ctrlInstance, createController;

beforeEach(function () {
  module('your_module');

  inject(function ($injector, $controller) {
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();

    createController = function (bindStuff) {
      ctrlInstance = $controller('formStuffCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope
      });

      Object.keys(bindStuff).forEach(function (key) {
        ctrlInstance[key] = bindStuff[key];
      });
    });
  });
});


it('exposes the "statsStuff stuff"', function () {
  var stats = { x: 500, y: 1000 };
  createController({ stats: stats });
  expect(ctrlInstance.stats).to.deep.equal(stats);
});
```

---

Even without the bindToController 'emulation', I would highly recommend the `createController` way of instantiating your controller as it gives you the flexibility of manipulating the controllers *dependencies* before hand (without the need of another `before|beforeEach` block).

---

*: I say to some extent, as this is attaching the properties *after* the controller has been instantiated, whereas `bindToController` attaches the properties before hand. So there may very well be some discrepancies between the two.